# What to do when Juju machine 0 has got "agent-state: not-started" state

Tags: juju

After running a Juju environment for some time, now machine 0 has got status: "agent-state: not-started" that has persisted for some time now and it is unable to deploy any new machines.

"Juju ssh 0" gives Waiting for machine to come up". I have also tried rebooting it from Amazon EC2 console without any change.

What do I do to to get it up again?

Comment: I am able to log into the machine using "ssh ubuntu@[public IP]", and /var/log/juju/machine-agent.log says:

Failure: txzookeeper.client.ConnectionTimeoutException: could not connect before timeout

Same error in /var/log/juju/provision-agent.log in addition to:

"2013-03-25 11:00:46,661: juju.agents.provision@INFO: Stopping provisioning agent"

Comment: Zooinspector also works from machine 0.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like I experienced the following bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/995823

Workaround is to run `sudo restart jujud-machine-0` after ssh-ing into it directly using `ssh ubuntu@[public IP]`, where public IP is found from the machine list (`juju status`).